# Georeference at CartoDB?

Tags: carto, geocoding

If I georeference New York (I do not have a country column) it only finds New York in the UK. This happens to a lot of other cities.

What can I do to change that (except adding a country column)?

Is there some kind of workaround?

Maybe another tool that has a more advanced database?

Comment: http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/how_to_georeference.html there is an option to for country

Comment: Yes, but I do not want to add a country column to my database as I have loads of cities...

Comment: You may have missed a line in the help file: "Choose your table column containing the country names for each of your cities in the second selector. **If you don’t have one, you can choose “Free text input” and type in one value that will apply to all of your cities, such as “USA”.**" Are you saying you have cities in different countries and you want it to find potential matches in all countries, without specifying one?

Comment: Hey Chirs, thanks for helping me. Yes I have several cities in several countries and I am just supprised that it does not seem to geocode some of them (often big ones, like New York) right...

Comment: I don't know how CartoDB's locator(s) work. 'Right' is relative - with an ArcGIS locator for example, I would expect such a result to fail/be unmatched but then present me with a list of possible matches to choose from. On the other hand, if it finds a match with a high enough score it would just accept it (even if wrong). It really just depends on the locator, but I also wouldn't expect great results from matches based on a single field that could potentially have duplicates and not giving it anything else to go on. How do *you* know it's the wrong city (as in is there some other attribute)?

Answer (score 1):

The city names geocoder that CartoDB offers uses data from GeoNames, which is using "New York City" for New York. This is why by using New York the one from the UK was appearing, as it's selected due to the amount of population.

We have done some changes with respect to the synonyms of the cities and now geocoding "New York" will give you the city in the state of New York, USA.

For other cities, I recommend you to select the column of the city and the column of the country in which it is. Of course, using the column of the region in which the city is (for example, the state) will give you the best accuracy.